# Home link for JSDoc with clean-jsdoc-theme not working

Tags: javascript, html, jsdoc

I installed clean-jsdoc-theme with `npm install clean-jsdoc-theme --save-dev`. It works great except the home button defaults to

`/path/to/folder/containing/docs/`

which displays the folder's contents but does not display the `index.html` home page for the doc. I tried adding

```
"opts": {
    "encoding": "utf8",
    "readme": "./README.md",
    "destination": "docs/",
    "recurse": true,
    "verbose": true,
    "template": "./node_modules/clean-jsdoc-theme",
    "theme_opts": {
        "base_url": "../../../public/index.html"
    }
},
```

to reset the base URL to the right folder, but this just goes to `/public/index.html` instead of the relative path. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also faced the same problem, but it will automatically get solved when you host your document.

You can add readme.md, in which you can add information about your doc, so it will be visible at home page.

```
"opts": {
"template": "node_modules/clean-jsdoc-theme",
"readme": "./readme/readme.md",
"recurse": true,
"destination": "./docs/",
"encoding": "utf8",
"verbose": true,
"theme_opts": {
  "default_theme": "dark",
  "search": true,
  "title": "Home",
  "homepageTitle": "Docs"
} },
```

See here ----> [readme.md file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h8LnQ.png)

As I have hosted doc on GitHub Pages, You can see below.....it is working, when you click on "Home" it will only show your index.html (main) file i.e it will show you the contents of readme.md file, it won't show you the directory contents.

See here ----> [Documentation on GitHub Pages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k01cO.png)